# Android Canvas - restrict draw area

Tags: android, canvas

So on my canvas I have few rectangular areas where I draw different bitmaps.
Sometimes bitmaps get outside of their respective areas. I want these bitmaps to be cut off, so only the portion of bitmap inside of it's area is drawn.

I sure can calculate it manually (srcRect and dstRect)...
But isn't there a simpler solution?

I found clipBounds, but it doesn't seem to restrict drawing area in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is [`Canvas.clipRect()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipRect(android.graphics.Rect)). You will need to know the bounds of the clipping rectangle, of course, but you don't need to worry about calculating a custom `srcRect`.

To use, `save()` the `Canvas`, do a single `drawBitmap()`, then `restore()` it to get your original clipping state back:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.clipRect(...);
canvas.drawBitmap(...);
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: Yep, just tested it out - works like a charm. Too bad I've already done it "the old fashioned way" =/